# Webservice call freezing ipad app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, asihttprequest

I have an app in which i am trying to call a webservice using asihttp . Everything working fine but the problem is none of my action buttons are not working when the service call in progress after completing the call all are working fine. Below is my code

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    [request setAuthenticationScheme:(NSString *)kCFHTTPAuthenticationSchemeBasic];
    [request setUsername:usrname];
    [request setPassword:passwrd];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDownloadDestinationPath:JsonPath];
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

I have tested both with synchronous and asynchronous but same problem.

Comment: try calling this method from background thread..

Comment: You should check out [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com) because ASI is not maintained any more.

Comment: Use the NSOperation. :)

Answer (score 1):

Call download method in background thread.

Once download complete call updateUI method on main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Where as i know ASIHTTP calls their method in main thread. You can use `AFNetWorking` for faster response [here](http://afnetworking.com/)

Answer (score 1):

use [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t jsonParsingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("jsonParsingQueue", NULL);


    dispatch_async(jsonParsingQueue, ^{
        @try {
             //call webservise code
       }
 }
        @catch (NSException * e) {
            NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);


        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


            //table reload or other code

        });
    });
```